# How to run one query from another query result. (Count down-line in Uni-level MLM)

Tags: php, mysql

Currently working on Uni-level Marketing project and getting error to count down-line, I write this code.

```
require("db_conn.php");
$stmt1 = $dbsh->prepare("SELECT * FROM sthp_loginfo WHERE shil_rfc=:dfdfd"); 
$stmt1->bindParam("dfdfd", $_SESSION['shusm'],PDO::PARAM_STR) ;
$stmt1->execute();
$dlcount1 =+ $stmt1->rowCount();
$result1 = $stmt1->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if($stmt1->rowCount() > 0){
  foreach ($stmt1 as $row1) {
        $stmt2 = $dbsh->prepare("SELECT * FROM sthp_loginfo WHERE shil_rfc=:sgsdd"); 
        $stmt2->bindParam("sgsdd", $row1['shil_usm'],PDO::PARAM_STR) ;
        $stmt2->execute();
        $dlcount2 =+$stmt2->rowCount();
        $result2 = $stmt2->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        if($stmt2->rowCount() > 0){
        foreach ($stmt2 as $row2) {
            $stmt3 = $dbsh->prepare("SELECT * FROM sthp_loginfo WHERE shil_rfc=:dfhfdh"); 
            $stmt3->bindParam("dfhfdh", $row2['shil_usm'],PDO::PARAM_STR) ;
            $stmt3->execute();
            $dlcount3 =+$stmt3->rowCount();
            $result3 = $stmt3->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            if($stmt3->rowCount() > 0){
            foreach ($stmt3 as $row3) {
                $stmt4 = $dbsh->prepare("SELECT * FROM sthp_loginfo WHERE shil_rfc=:rhrrhr"); 
                $stmt4->bindParam("rhrrhr", $row3['shil_usm'],PDO::PARAM_STR) ;
                $stmt4->execute();
                $dlcount4 =+$stmt4->rowCount();
                $result4 = $stmt4->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                if($stmt4->rowCount() > 0){
                foreach ($stmt4 as $row4) {
                    $stmt5 = $dbsh->prepare("SELECT * FROM sthp_loginfo WHERE shil_rfc=:fbfbf"); 
                    $stmt5->bindParam("fbfbf", $row4['shil_usm'],PDO::PARAM_STR) ;
                    $stmt5->execute();
                    $dlcount5 =+$stmt5->rowCount();
                    $result5 = $stmt5->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                    if($stmt5->rowCount() > 0){
                    foreach ($stmt5 as $row5) {
                        $stmt6 = $dbsh->prepare("SELECT * FROM sthp_loginfo WHERE shil_rfc=:shyht"); 
                        $stmt6->bindParam("shyht", $row5['shil_usm'],PDO::PARAM_STR) ;
                        $stmt6->execute();
                        $dlcount6 =+$stmt6->rowCount();
                        $result6 = $stmt6->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                        if($stmt6->rowCount() > 0){
                        foreach ($stmt6 as $row6) {
                            $stmt7 = $dbsh->prepare("SELECT * FROM sthp_loginfo WHERE shil_rfc=:jhrtger"); 
                            $stmt7->bindParam("jhrtger", $row6['shil_usm'],PDO::PARAM_STR) ;
                            $stmt7->execute();
                            $dlcount7 =+$stmt7->rowCount();
                            $ttdown = $dlcount1+$dlcount2+$dlcount3+$dlcount4+$dlcount5+$dlcount6+$dlcount7;
                            $stmt7 =null;
                        }}
                        else{$ttdown = $dlcount1+$dlcount2+$dlcount3+$dlcount4+$dlcount5+$dlcount6;}
                        $stmt6 =null;
                    }}
                    else{$ttdown = $dlcount1+$dlcount2+$dlcount3+$dlcount4+$dlcount5;}
                    $stmt5 =null;
                }}
                else{$ttdown = $dlcount1+$dlcount2+$dlcount3+$dlcount4;}
                $stmt4 =null;
            }}
            else{$ttdown = $dlcount1+$dlcount2+$dlcount3;}
            $stmt3 =null;
        }}
        else{$ttdown = $dlcount1+$dlcount2;}
        $stmt2 =null;
    }
}else{$ttdown = $ttdown = $dlcount1;}
$stmt1 =null;
```

MySQL database table

```
id | name | username | referred-by
1  | abc  | abc      | demo
2  | abc1 | abc1     | abc
3  | abc2 | abc2     | abc1
4  | abc3 | abc3     | abc2
```

**For username abc total referrals/team is 3**

This code is working but for each time I need to put this big code. Is there any why to count downline in smaller code or is it right way to do?

Also for print downline I need to run this code for each level, is there any easy way?

Comment: All of these queries look very similar. Why do you execute them one after the other? Why not do everything in SQL?

Comment: thanks for attention....how to do that?

Comment: To answer that we would need to see your DB schema, know which DB you are using, and what are those SQL queries meant to do.

Comment: Please check, I edited my question.